# Passing callable object to constructor taking std::function

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++14, c++17, move-semantics

I am struggling with passing an callable object with overloaded operator bool. It posses also unique_ptr for data so copying was disabled.
I am trying to pass such a object to another object whose constructor takes std::function, I believe it is totally legal.

See example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class invoker
{
    public:
        invoker(function<bool(void)> fnc_):
            fnc { move(fnc_) }
        {}
        ~invoker() = default;    
    private:
        function<bool(void)> fnc;
};

class action
{
  public:
    action() = default;
    ~action() = default;
    action(const action& rhs) = delete;
    action& operator=(const action& rhs) = delete;

    action(action&& rhs):
        data { move(rhs.data)}
    {
    }
    action& operator=(action&& rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
        {
            data = std::move(rhs.data);
        }
    }

    bool operator()()
    {
        return true;
    }

  private:    
    unique_ptr<int> data;
};

int main()
{
    auto runner = std::make_unique<invoker>(std::move(action {}));
    //unique_ptr<invoker> runner(new invoker(action() ));

    return 0;
}
```

Why does compiler complain?

```
> /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1710:34: error: use of deleted function
> 'action::action(const action&)'
>     __dest._M_access<_Functor*>() =
```

Comment: do you see the function signature here `'action::action(const action&)'` ? compiler complains that you have used your copy-constructor of class `action` after you deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

You pass the `std::function` *by value* to the constructor. That means it must be *copied*. And its contents (like the `action` object it wraps) can *not* be copied since you deleted the copy-constructor.

The `action` object can't be copied anyway since it contain an uncopyable member (the `data` member variable). You don't need to explicitly delete the copy-constructor, it would have been deleted anyway because of the member.

Your best bet to solve this is to use a lambda as argument instead of creating the (temporary) `action` object.

Comment: But I am using std::move, doesn't it cast it to r-value and shouldn't then use std::function move constructor? I would also " std::function satisfies the requirements of CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable." isn't it the case ?

Comment: @Lukasz The problem is that you're not creating a `std::function` directly, instead it has to be created *indirectly* which isn't really possible. You move the `action` object, not the `std::function` object.

Comment: I don't think your reason is correct.  `std::function foo{action {}};` [also fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2180d0c04293c098)

Comment: @Lukasz Indeed my reasoning is partially incorrect (as noted by Nathan). The `std::function` object needs a *copy* of the callable object, which isn't really possible with the `action  class. It doens't matter if you move the `action` object or not, the `std::function` object still needs to copy it. And as I noted before, you don't move the `std::function` object, but the `action` object.